# How to retreive a variable in Javascript HTML file and then map it to a code.gs function

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, template-engine

How can I store a variable in Javascript HTML file and then map it to a code.gs function.

Objective:

I want to retrieve var today value from HTML file and then map it to date_preset variable in Code.gs file

I tried doing something like this but it doesn't work:

```
act_XXXXXX/insights?date_preset=<?!= today; ?>
```

Javascript.html

```html
<script>

  var today = document.getElementById('today').value;
  
</script>
```

HTML File

```html
<body>
<div class="block form-group">
  <label for="select">Date Range</label>
  <select id="select">
    <option selected id="today" value="today">Today</option>
   </script>
</div>

<?!= include('Javascript'); ?>

</body>
```

Code.gs

```
function apiRequest () {

const base = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/';
  
  const endpoint = 'act_XXXXXX/insights?date_preset=XXX&campaign,impressions,spend;

}
```

Comment: How are you rendering the HTML file?

Comment: Through this function:

```
/**
 * show sidebar v3
 */
function showSidebar3() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Fields')
      .evaluate()
      .setTitle('xxxx')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen on the client-side (using JS in your HTML) for when the user selects an option, get the value and send it to code.gs. Using [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) you tell the server-side which function to execute. In your case to makes API call with the value you sent.

Have a read at the [client-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) articles in the documentation.

Notice how they serve HTML with a `<script>` which contains a function "google.script.run" which allows to call functions in the server side.

#### Example:

Suppose you are deploying a web app with Apps Script, then:

```js
// Code.gs
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function apiRequest(params) {
  var today = params[0];
  // Your logic here
}
```

and:

```html
<!-- Index.html -->
<body>
    <div class="block form-group">
        <label for="select">Date Range</label>
        <select id="select">
            <option selected id="today" value="today">Today</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <script>
    var today = document.getElementById('today').value;
    var account_id = document.getElementById('account_id').value;
    var etc = document.getElementById('etc').value;
    var params = [today,account_id,etc]; 
      google.script.run.apiRequest(params);
    </script>
</body>
```

This sends a signal to execute `apiRequest(today)`

Comment: I want to retrieve multiple variables form DOM HTML such as today, account ID and etc. should I include them in the function paramter such as apiRequest(today,account_ID) like this? @Aerials

Comment: Sending an Array is what I would do to pass multiple params. I edited the example in the answer to show so